# Want to use a function only on a specific element in the mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

i'm trying to replace my p tag by an input tag, its already working but my problem is that the function execute on all item from my .map , and i want only to display the one where i click on edit. I can already get the id from my with my console log but i dont know the way to use it to identify which one have to execute the function.
Thanks for all who will find a way to solve it!

```
<tbody>
            {carsList.map((val, key) => {
              const handleclick = (id) => {
              
                setUnShow(current => !current)
                setIsShow(current => !current)
                console.log(id)
              };
        return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<input type="text" 
                  onChange={(event) =>  {newsetCarsName(event.target.value)}} 
                  placeholder={val.carsName}
                  />)}
                  {isShow && (<p>{val.carsName}</p>)}
                </th>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<input type="text" 
                  onChange={(event) =>  {newsetModel(event.target.value)}} 
                  placeholder={val.carsModels}
                  />)}
                  {isShow && (<p>{val.carsModels}</p>)}
                </th>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<input type="text" 
                  onChange={(event) =>  {newsetDate(event.target.value)}}
                  placeholder={val.carsDate}
                  />)}
                  {isShow && (<p>{val.carsDate}</p>)}
                </th>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<input type="text" 
                  onChange={(event) =>  {newsetNbkm(event.target.value)}} 
                  placeholder={val.carsNbkm}
                  />)}
                  {isShow && (<p>{val.carsNbkm}</p>)}
                </th>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<input type="text" 
                  onChange={(event) =>  {newsetPrice(event.target.value)}} 
                  placeholder={val.carsPrice}
                  />)}
                  {isShow && (<p>{val.carsPrice}</p>)}
                </th>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<input type="text" 
                  onChange={(event) =>  {newsetPowch(event.target.value)}}
                  placeholder={val.carsPowch}
                  />)}
                  {isShow && (<p>{val.carsPowch}</p>)}
                </th>

                <th scope='row'>
                  <button onClick={() => Delete(val._id)}>Delete</button>
                  </th>
                <th scope='row'>
                  {unShow && (<button onClick={EditConfirm}>Modifier</button>)}
                  {isShow && (<button onClick={() => handleclick(val._id)}>Edit</button>)}
                  {unShow && (<button onClick={() => handleclick(val._id)}>Annuler</button>)}
                  </th>
              </tr>
        )
})}
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a component with a lot of ternary and conditional display, return a component for unShow and another one for isShow